# Align object to edge | "Fence-generator"

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to build a 'Fence-Generator'. For that i did simple path from points connected with edges.

What i did so far:

Aligned fence-poles to verticies and fences-walls to edge centers. but now i want the rotation of fences-walls to match the rotation of the edges.

I tried to calculate the angle but i didn't got it to work.

Any help on how i can calculate the right rotation for the wall would really be appreciated!

Loop Setup for Pole and Wall Generation:
[image: Loop Setup for Pole and Wall Generation]
Object and loop initialization:
[image: Objects Setup]
Current State. I want the walls rotation to follow the edges.
[image: Current State]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the base wall object is aligned along X and long 1 unit.

You can have the angle using the angle from the edge to X axis.

So if you have the vector `<e1, e2>` of the edge, the angle is given by atan2 (arctangent B/A in Nodes) from x, y componants of `<e1, e2>`.

Note: in the nodes below, have used iterations on object and edges instead of by index access.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Lemon,
Thanks alot! That did it.
Have a nice Day! =D